# MacOsX rpmbuild --target noarch doesn't work

Tags: java, rpmbuild

I have java project with building rpm by maven. Required create noarch packets, but i see concrete arch.
I install rpm(4.4.9 or 5.2.0) via macports at MacOsX, and run command from maven rpm plugin:

```
sudo rpmbuild -bb -v --buildroot /path/to/project/buildroot --target noarch java-search-qt.spec
Building target platforms: noarch
Executing(%install): /bin/bash -e /tmp/rpm-tmp.69257
+ umask 022
+ cd /opt/local/src/macports/BUILD
+ /bin/rm -rf /path/to/project/target/rpm/project/buildroot
+ /bin/rm -rf /path/to/project/target/rpm/project/buildroot
+ '[' -e /path/to/project/target/rpm/project/buildroot ']'
+ mv /path/to/project/target/rpm/project/tmp-buildroot /path/to/project/target/rpm/project/buildroot
+ /opt/local/lib/rpm/brp-compress
+ /opt/local/lib/rpm/brp-strip
+ /opt/local/lib/rpm/brp-strip-static-archive
+ /opt/local/lib/rpm/brp-strip-comment-note
+ /opt/local/lib/rpm/brp-nobuildrootpath
Processing files: java-search-qt-1.0.17-1
Finding  Provides: /opt/local/lib/rpm/find-provides
Finding  Requires: /opt/local/lib/rpm/find-requires
Requires(interp): /bin/bash /bin/bash /bin/bash /bin/bash
Requires(verify): /bin/bash
Requires(pre): /bin/bash
Requires(post): /bin/bash
Requires(postun): /bin/bash
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /opt/local/lib/rpm/check-files /path/to/project/target/rpm/project/buildroot
Wrote: /opt/local/src/macports/RPMS/i386/project.i386.rpm
```

Maven plugin use option "--target noarch", but rpmbuild fully ignore it's. Expected noarch.rpm file, why rpmbuild create i386 at 4.4.9 version and x86?

Update

I found one working variant of call rpmbuilder, builds *.noarch.rpm file:

```
rpmbuild -bb --target noarch-linux-pc project.spec
```

Another variants, build *.i386.rpm file:

```
rpmbuild -bb --buildroot /path/to/buildroot --target noarch-linux-pc project.spec
rpmbuild -bb --define '_topdir /path/to/topdir' --target noarch-linux-pc project.spec
```

I can't understand. Any ideas?

P.S. Sorry for my english, it's difficult language for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the mistake!

The maven-rpm-plugin tool sucks. This package contains class RPMHelper, and uses bash command builder. The rpmbuild tool requires strong param ordering, and this class ignore all rules. I changed param ordering, and now I have correctly builded rpm packet.
From what I see, codehaus command is no longer support. I think that need we need a fork on github.

Answer (score 6):

I have different versions of everything, but on OS X, using RPM 5.4.14 and rpm-maven-plugin 2.1-alpha-3, I can create a noarch RPM for Linux by specifying:

```
<needarch>noarch</needarch>
<targetOS>linux</targetOS>
```

rpm-maven-plugin says:

```
[INFO] Building target platforms: noarch-apple-linux
```

From the command line, checking the package, all looks well:

```
rpm -qp --qf 'Arch:%{ARCH} OS:%{OS}\n' my-rpm-0.0.1-1.noarch.rpm 
Arch:noarch OS:linux
```

... and the result installs happily on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with building on MacOSX but I thought I'd post our `pom.xml` file here as a reference:

> http://pastebin.com/dHVA4yZ1

The maven command line we use under CentOS Linux is:

```
mvn clean compile rpm:attached-rpm deploy
```

This deploys our RPMs and also creates:

```
target/rpm/mprew-behavior/RPMS/noarch/mprew-behavior-2.12.0s-19068.noarch.rpm
```

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thanks, but threre's no problem of plugin - binary tool [rpmbuild](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/rpmbuild.8.html) have strange behavior at '--target' option

Comment: According to the RPM plugin the default is `noarch`.  What version of rpmbuild are you using?  WE're using RPM version 4.4.2.  http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/ident-params.html#needarch

Comment: And you are not specifying a source architecture, right?  http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/source-params.html#targetArchitecture

Comment: Current available macport rpm version is 4.4.9, and I use it . As I know, latest version 5.3.x.

Yes, I'm not specifying architecture, because I need noarch! At linux works correctly, as result I see *.noarch.rpm file. But only on mac rpmbuild create *.i386.rpm file. I'm try set targetArchitecture as noarch, but it's ignored by builder.

Comment: Sounds like you are doing it all correctly.  Sorry to not be of help.  This is an interesting thread.  They use: `--target 'noarch-apple-mac os x' with * on either side.  Good luck.  http://old.nabble.com/-jira--Created%3A-(MRPM-67)-rpm-goal-always-fails-on-Mac-OS-X-td27844879.html